# Is this comma supposed to be here?

Tags: http, cookies

I'm setting a few cookies from PHP and they're being sent back to my browser, but this is what's being returned. From what I can tell, there's a comma present that should be a semi-colon. This wouldn't bother me if the browser was setting any cookies, but it isn't so I figure this is the issue. Here's the Set-Cookie string:

```
PHPSESSID=stringhere; path=/, cookie1=stringhere; expires=Thu, 02-Aug-2012 06:50:32 GMT; path=/; domain=example.com; httponly, cookie2=stringhere; expires=Thu, 02-Aug-2012 06:50:33 GMT; path=/; domain=example.com
```

The first comma is the one I'm talking about.

Edit: Note the PHPSESSID cookie does get set.

Comment: Do `cookie1` and `cookie2` get set? What are your PHP and webserver versions? What code do you use to set the cookies? Folding multiple cookies on one Set-Cookie header is allowed (although a server complying with RFC 6265 [SHOULD NOT](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-3) do so), if the server separates them by comma. This won't always work correctly because of the `expires` format.

Comment: Cookie1 and Cookie2 do not - they are sent but never saved. PHP 5.2.17 is the PHP version, can't find the server version.. I'll look in to preventing set-cookie "folding". Thanks!